# How to get ENS domain address with Moralis

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, metamask, moralis

I am using Moralis for my DApp, after I login with Meatmask. I wonder how to get my registered ENS domain address. From the logged `user` object, I can not find any useful info.

```
  const serverUrl = "https://xxxxx/server";
  const appId = "YOUR_APP_ID";
  Moralis.start({ serverUrl, appId });

  // add from here down
  async function login() {
    let user = Moralis.User.current();
    if (!user) {
      user = await Moralis.authenticate();
    }
    console.log("logged in user:", user);
    const userEthNFTs = await Moralis.Web3API.account.getNFTs();
    console.log("====== userEthNFTs: ", userEthNFTs);
  }
```

I do see my ENS nft got printed out, but I do not see any "name" in it, it only shows:

```
amount: "1"​​​
block_number: "13809918"​​​
block_number_minted: "13809918"​​​
contract_type: "ERC721"​​​
frozen: 0​​​
is_valid: 0​​​
metadata: null​​​
name: ""​​​
owner_of: "0xf...4"​​​
symbol: ""​​​
synced_at: null​​​
syncing: 1​​​
token_address: "0x57f1887a8bf19b14fc0df6fd9b2acc9af147ea85"​​​
token_id: "9215...."​​​
token_uri: null
```

I did a little more research on this, and found out `ethers.js` has `lookupAddress` function which can do it, but this reverse lookup feature is not supported in `web3js`. However, Moralis only has web3js provider, is there any plans to add ethers provider?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found https://admin.moralis.io/web3Api: 1 GET ​/resolve​/{address}​/reverse Return the ENS domain when available (Only for ETH)